# Low budget, 70s look, about aliens wearing tunics and old vessels sailing the desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie or TV show when I was a little child in the 80s. It had a low budget, 70s look. I can remember only two scenes from it.

In the first, there is a guy with a cow boy hat and a gun, Magnum like; I think he was inside the typical American dinner restaurant. He shoots an alien. The alien wears a tunic and some sort of metallic triangular helmet pointing downwards. When he is shot, his body seems to disappear, and his tunic and helmet fall to the ground.

The other scene is about a vessel, like a caravel, sailing through the desert, not water, with some people on it. Maybe, the guy travelling on it is the same one who shot the alien.

Comment: I think you mean desert, not [dessert](https://img.taste.com.au/44mhGT_T/w720-h480-cfill-q80/taste/2016/11/better-than-brad-pitt-five-layer-dessert-108653-1.jpeg)

Comment: this is one episode of the martian chronicles

Comment: That duplicate really isn't very similar except in that the same series is the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This sounds very much like the first part of [Ray Bradbury's The Martian Chronicles](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080242/).

[image]

1980, downward facing masks as you can see in the cover photo on IMDB there.

The opening scene, if I recall, is set in a building like a roadside diner, and the people travel across the deserts in ship-like vehicles.

There's also a fair bit of hat-wearing:
[image]